# Can you make an EditText input from right to left?

Tags: android, input, android-edittext

I was wondering if you can control input on an EditText to move from right to left?  The EditText would have to support insert/delete etc. from right to left as well.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What is actually what you're trying to achieve? You might want to insert an arabic char that will add this behaviour to a text field. It has to be the first char, but I have no idea which char it might be.

Comment: I have a (American)currency field with a mask, I would like entry to move from right to left.

Comment: @Loïc Faure-Lacroix  yes when i write in arabic then we can see text from right to left

Comment: android:textDirection="locale" or rtl

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to set gravity to the right.

Comment: @Rich.......if we set Gravity to right side that just we can set text to right side.

Comment: He is asking for the text to write from right to left, not right alight the text.  The work "RIGHT" would then be written "THGIR"

Comment: @CamilleSévigny I don't believe that's true.  In the comments (s)he says it's an American currency field.  Entering 1-0-0-0 in that order should not be displayed as 0001 if it's a currency field.  It should be displayed as $10.00.  It should be displayed in the order it is entered, but aligned to the right.  You don't type 4-3-2-1 to enter $12.34 in any type of system for working with American currency...not a cash register in the country works this way.  3 downvotes on this answer, but what (s)he was really asking was just how to right-align the text.

Answer (score 29):

Add this to your editText

```
        android:textDirection="rtl"
```

Comment: Keep this as a note:- android:textDirection requires API level 17

Answer (score 15):

Just use this:

```
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:textAlignment="viewStart"
```

Answer (score 8):

The right way is to use:

```
android:textAlignment="viewStart"
```

As it will automatically work for LTR and RTL.

Answer (score 2):

try this code

```
//initialize
EditText userName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userName);

//set gravity for userName 
userName.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the manual way to do it by using the following code :

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        // Each time click Menu button on the bar
        // Set the cursor to the first index
        mEtEmail.setSelection(0); // YOUR EDIT TEXT
    } 
    
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

*p/s : Or you can change*

> KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU

Or you can try with [Bidi](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/Bidi.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can add to your edittext in xml:

in case of left to right :

```
   android:textDirection="firstStrongLtr"
```

in case of right to left :

```
   android:textDirection="firstStrongRtl"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_supporter_last_name"
            style="@style/TextInputEditText"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:maxLength="10"
            android:padding="@dimen/default_margin" />
```

**OUTPUT :**

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Try This....

1. Initialize User name and password fields.

   ```
   EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);

   EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
   ```
2. Get current Locale for RTL languages like Arabic etc,.

   ```
   String getCurrentLocale = Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();
   ```
3. Then we should check which language is selected for RTL or LTR.

   ```
   if(getCurrentLocale.equalEgnoreCase("English")){          //LTR languages

         username.setGravity(Gravity.Left);

         password.setGravity(Gravity.Left);

    }else{                                                     //RTL languages

        username.setGravity(Gravity.Right);

        password.setGravity(Gravity.Right);

    }
   ```