# How do I position the cursor on the right in EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, right-to-left

My application uses [RTL language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left) (right to left).

When the `EditText` field gets focus, the cursor appears on the left and only when the user starts to type, the cursor (and the RTL text) moves right.
When the user clicks "enter" to start a new line, the cursor moves to the left again.

When I use `android:gravity="right"`, the cursor is OK (on the right) but as the user starts to type the text always moves to the the other side (RTL text moves left).

Any ideas how I can align text to the right AND keep the text direction?

Comment: I too searching about this only..If  you got the answer means..Please let me know..

Comment: Still no answer, but I found that on some devices this behavior is different that others.
I work with Hebrew enabled devices and Galaxy S behavior is different than Galaxy S2. I guess its the installed ROM that matters.
I havn't tested it on Ice cream sandwich yet, where RTL language support comes as standard.

If my question was relevant to you, I would appreciate it if you click ^ (up) on it.

Comment: If your app is not multilingual, you can align the TextView field only to the right (so it could "stretch" to the left). It works when the field is a single line.

Comment: Try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6624186/758458

Comment: have you found any solution to this problem please answer this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314356/hebrew-keyboard-changes-edittext-gravity

Comment: [Try this... for RTL text direction at run time.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083768/can-you-make-an-edittext-input-from-right-to-left/21397832#21397832

Comment: Check this answer it contains a workaround, http://stackoverflow.com/a/34927271/1826581

Answer (score 19):

Its works for me

```
      <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="right" />
```

`ellipsize` is important

It solves your problem

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into the native RTL support that was introduced in Android 4.2 Jelly Bean.

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/jelly-bean.html

Android 4.2 introduces full native support for RTL (right-to-left) layouts, including layout mirroring. With native RTL support, you can deliver the same great app experience to all of your users, whether their language uses a script that reads right-to-left or one that reads left-to-right.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and I am able to fix this by setting `android:textDirection` in my EditText. e.g

```
android:textDirection="inherit"
```

you can change the value of **textDirection** as per your requirement. I have taken it as **inherit** because user are able to change the language with in app. So if user has selected language like english or hindi then it will start typing from **left-to-right direction**, but if user has selected language like urdu then it will start typing **right-to-left direction**.

For this your app **minimum API level** should be **17**.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, `android:gravity = right` only makes the text jusified to the right. But what you want cannot be done with this. You can call a `ontouch` event in the `textbox` and add the new character to the right of the current text and display it again.....

Answer (score 0):

**Starting from API Level>=17**

We can use [android:layoutDirection](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#layoutDirection) in edit text. Also `android:gravity="end"` should also works.