# Android Edit Text - Cursor stays at the starting position

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am using an Edit Text in my project.

The problem is that whenever I type anything into the text box, it shows up, but the cursor does not move from its starting position at all, regardless of how many characters I type. Also I am not able to move by clicking to any particular character in the text box.

My xml file for containing the edit text is like this

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/xEt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="295dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
android:focusable="true" >
```

The xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/xsubLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

    </RelativeLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/xEt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="295dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/xK1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <include android:id="@+id/xKeyBoard" layout="@layout/gf"></include>
        <include android:id="@+id/xtop" layout="@layout/top"></include>
                <include android:id="@+id/x11" layout="@layout/x1"></include>
        <include android:id="@+id/x12" layout="@layout/x3"></include>
        <include android:id="@+id/x13" layout="@layout/x4"></include>
        <include android:id="@+id/x14" layout="@layout/x5"></include>

        <include android:id="@+id/x15" layout="@layout/x6"></include>
        <include android:id="@+id/x16" layout="@layout/x7"></include>
        <include android:id="@+id/x17" layout="@layout/x8"></include>
        <include android:id="@+id/x18" layout="@layout/x9"></include>

        <include android:id="@+id/x19" layout="@layout/x10"></include>
        <include android:id="@+id/x20" layout="@layout/x11"></include>

        <include android:id="@+id/x22" layout="@layout/x13"></include>

        <include android:id="@+id/x23" layout="@layout/x14"></include>
        <include android:id="@+id/x24" layout="@layout/x15"></include>
        <include android:id="@+id/x25" layout="@layout/x16"></include>
        <include android:id="@+id/x26" layout="@layout/x17"></include>

        <include android:id="@+id/x27" layout="@layout/x18"></include>
        <include android:id="@+id/x28" layout="@layout/x19"></include>


    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: did you test in different devices/emulator for this?

Comment: then first test it may be its device problem. If getting same thing happen then tell us

Comment: @Pratik It is not a device problem. I tried it on a handset, but got the same results

Comment: @Pratik Also , my edit text is having a limited number of characters that can be written to it

Comment: @Pratik I am using multi line edit text...is that creating the problem?

Comment: @Pratik : When I use mEt.setSelection(mEt.getText().length()); it works for me, but will I have to write this everytime I make a change to the edit Text??

Comment: could you please post your code in question for using this edittext

Comment: @Pratik i cannot post the code. But I have already told you what is happening.

Comment: Firstly, my cursor does not move from my start position . Secondly, I am not able to scroll. Actually, I am using my own keypad and not the default one. Maybe that is creating a problem

Answer (score 7):

In my case, it was caused by using:

`android:textAllCaps="true"`

in the EditText element of my xml layout.

When I removed it, it worked as expected

Comment: Why should android:textAllCaps="true" cause this?

Comment: I've lost several hours because of this! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Are you binding you view to a model? i.e. Do you have an MVVM setup?

If you do, make sure you do not have any cyclical update especially for a two-way binding i.e. if user types a character, you update your model which will in turn update the EditText control and repeat.

So depending on your Editext control properties, each time the model change updates it, it could have the cursor reset to the start position.

If this is the case, a simple equality check between the model value and the EditText text value before you update it from the model should fix the issue.

```
if (txtEdit.text != modelValue)
{
    txtEdit.text = modelValue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It may be a bit too late to answer this question. But even i faced the same problem by using custom Keyboard. The problem was solved for me too after adding the following line in the XML file for every edittext

> android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
>
> android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"

Like this

```
<Editext                
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:paddingLeft="2dp" 
 android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
 android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"/>
```

I have seen a lot of people searching for this so i have posted to the one relevant to my problem.

Comment: I'm having this exact problem and this didn't work for me. I'm developing my own keyboard IME too, and this text entry field is in the settings menu of the configuration options for the IME

Answer (score 1):

set these properties to your XML file

```
  <YourLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:focusable="true" 
     android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/xEt"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="295dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:cursorVisible="true"/> 

</YourLayout>
```

Try this.
and put this in your java code.

```
 EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.xEt);
 et.setSelection(et.getText().length());
```

Comment: No, it is still not working. What do I do? It remains in the starting position

Comment: I am not using the default keyboard.. I am using my own layout...is that creating a problem?

Comment: please post your layout file.

Comment: Nirav, I have to write this code et.setSelection(et.getText().length()); everywhere to achieve the result, since it works for just that moment when it is encountered. Also, I am not able to go back and edit the text. That is , once entered, I am not able to edit the characters. What do I do?

Comment: Logcat shows no errors. The code is too long to post here. All I can say is that I am using my own keyboard layout. Does that create a problem, since I am not using default keyboard?

Comment: no it won't create the problem at all because you have did it right.i guess your java code may contains errors.

Answer (score 1):

I am using this workaround for this problem, 
If characters are in English or digit characters then change EditText gravity to left else in another Language in my case it's in Arabic then will change gravity to left and the cursor will move in it's right way according to each language:

```
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if(s.length() > 0){
                    char c = s.charAt(0);
                     // characters are Enlgish or digits.
                    if ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || Character.isDigit(c)) {
                        editText.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                    }else {
                        editText.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);


                    }
                } 
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this issue, and it was when I was developing a custom Android keyboard IME.  None of these proposed solutions worked for me (on Android 12 mind you, much later versions than those used in some of these suggestions).

My problem was in fact caused be the issue [@MADol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4618266/madol) has identified above in that each time the state updated it set the cursor back to the home position (start of the field). I am using a text input field of type `AppCompatEditText` :

`var editText: AppCompatEditText`

And in my method that is responsible for updating the text value based on state updates and such I just added:

`editText.setSelection(editText.length())`

This post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217378/place-cursor-at-the-end-of-text-in-edittext) is where I found this solution.