# How to Make Android Text Cursor Following the End of Text in EditText boxes

Tags: android, text, cursor, arabic, right-to-left

I am working on an application support RTL justification and its work fine, but I have tried many times to make text cursor following the end of text while typing but I did not figure it out, if I type in English or any LTR languages, but that does not work with RTL languages such as Arabic.
Please take a look to screenshot below.
I am working on AVD 4.0.3, my smartphone OS is 4.1.2.

[image]

Comment: Do you solve this problem? If yes please let me know?

Comment: Check this answer it contains a workaround:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/34927271/1826581

Answer (score 0):

works for me

```
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="right"
            />
```

Comment: Sorry, ellipsize + gravity does not solve the issue.