# How to make EditText content expand off screen to the left

Tags: android

I'm programming a calculator, and text in the display is programmed to expand from left to right, however when the text reaches the edge of the display, the text expands off screen to the right. Is there a way to reverse this effect? I'm using EditText object as the display.

[image]

```
    <!-- calculator display-->
    <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/disp" 
        android:id = "@+id/display" 
        android:hint="@string/dispHint" 
        android:gravity="right"
        style="@style/display"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"/>
```

Comment: I think you are looking for something like this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083768/can-you-make-an-edittext-input-from-right-to-left. HTH.

Comment: @Gravitoid I don't think this is the same question. I know how to make text start from the right and extend to the left. The problem is I don't know how to make the text extend off screen to the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one...this may help you

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.test.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

     <TextView 
     android:id="@+id/tv"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_marginTop="98dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="20dp
     android:text="Name"
     />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="38dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="98dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:hint="naveen"
            android:maxWidth="250dp"
            android:lines="1" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It's hard for me to say because finished this project months ago.