# Can you make a EditText input from right to left in Android?

Tags: android-studio, android-edittext

I was asking if you can control input on an EditText to move from right to left? The EditText would have to support insert/delete etc. from right to left as well. **Like if I keep inserting 1, 2, 3 it would be like 321**. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: do you mean like how arabic is written? from right to left?

Answer (score 0):

Have a Look at this [Can you make an EditText input from right to left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083768/can-you-make-an-edittext-input-from-right-to-left). Anyways answer to your problem is `android:textDirection="rtl"`